# Nombre de objeto no valido SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Quiero crear función que permita generar un reporte de ventas por empleado,
en un determinado año. La función debe retornar: los datos del
empleado, la cantidad de pedidos registrados y el monto total por empleado. 
Esto es un ejercicio de un PDF y lo quiero adaptar a la base de datos Northwind para practicar.

Esta es mi funcion

```
CREATE FUNCTION REPORTEVENTAS(@ANO INT) RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN (SELECT EmployeeID AS 'ID',
     FirstName AS 'NOMBRE',
     LastName AS 'APELLIDO',
     COUNT(OD.OrderID) AS 'CANTIDAD',
     SUM(Quantity*UnitPrice)
     FROM [Order Details] OD
     INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
     INNER JOIN Employees E ON E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
     WHERE YEAR(O.OrderDate) = @ANO
     GROUP BY 'ID','NOMBRE')
```

Este es el error que me esta dando

```
Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Procedure REPORTEVENTAS, Line 13
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an 
outer reference.
```

Esta es la version de SQL que estoy utilizando

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (X64) 
Jun 12 2012 13:05:25 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

Comment: Tal vez estas ejecutando la query en otra bd?

Comment: verificaste el nombre de la tabla? corroboraste el espacio?

Comment: Creo que necesita USE NORTHWIND al principio o califica la tabla con el nombre del base de datos, como [Northwind].[Order Details]

Comment: Como dijo Levi, el problema era que ejecutandolo en otra bd y no me habia fijado... Pero ahora me esta dando error en el GROUP BY

Answer (score 3):

Todas los campos en el SELECT que no tengan una función de agregado deben estar en el GROUP BY.  Te faltaba el apellido. Además debes usar en el GROUP BY los nombres de los campos, no el alias que le colocas.

```
CREATE FUNCTION REPORTEVENTAS(@ANO INT) RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN (SELECT O.EmployeeID AS 'ID',
     E.FirstName AS 'NOMBRE',
     E.LastName AS 'APELLIDO',
     COUNT(OD.OrderID) AS 'CANTIDAD',
     SUM(Quantity*UnitPrice)
     FROM [Order Details] OD
     INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
     INNER JOIN Employees E ON E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
     WHERE YEAR(O.OrderDate) = @ANO
     GROUP BY O.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque no te esta reconociendo desde que BD proviene el objeto:

Prueba así:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION REPORTEVENTAS(@ANO INT) RETURNS TABLE
 AS

 RETURN (SELECT E.EmployeeID AS 'ID',
 E.FirstName AS 'NOMBRE',
 E.LastName AS 'APELLIDO',
 COUNT(OD.OrderID) AS 'CANTIDAD',
 SUM(Quantity*UnitPrice)
 FROM [NOMBRE_BD].[Order Details] OD
 INNER JOIN [NOMBRE_BD].[Orders] O ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
 INNER JOIN [NOMBRE_BD].[Employees] E ON E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
 WHERE YEAR(O.OrderDate) = @ANO
 GROUP BY 'E.EmployeeID','E.FirstName')
```

En [NOMBRE_BD]  recuerda reemplazar por el nombre de la Base de Datos.

Answer (score 0):

Si en los joins de las tablas pones un alias, debes referencias los campos con ese mismo alias, de lo contrario te generara error, ademas en el gurop by se ordena por el campo... intenta asi:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID AS 'ID',
     E.FirstName AS 'NOMBRE',
     E.LastName AS 'APELLIDO',
     COUNT(OD.OrderID) AS 'CANTIDAD',
     SUM(Quantity*UnitPrice)
     FROM [Order Details] OD
     INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
     INNER JOIN Employees E ON E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
     WHERE YEAR(O.OrderDate) = @ANO
     GROUP BY 'E.EmployeeID','E.FirstName'
```